# Let's rage against [range]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The current tag-wiki for [range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/range) is as follows:

> A range is an extent of values between its lower and upper bound. It
>   can refer to a DOM Range, the Ruby Range class, the [Python `range`
>   function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
>   or [PostgreSQL's range
>   types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html).

That's 4 things at **once** in a tag. Additionally when flying over the questions in that tag, it seems like this is also used for Range objects in VBA/EXCEL context and probably some other stuff, e.g. [owl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/owl).

This tag is ambiguous, and thus overly broad. It's unlikely to attract anything like a consistent question body.

Questions with this tag most probably should get much more specific tags (think [python-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-range), [value-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value-range), [range-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/range-type), ...)

I say let's burn it... because retagging a whooping 3.4k questions seems like wasted effort to me

Comment: Contextual tags are important.

Comment: While they surely are, I don't think they're helping much when they are this ambiguous :( the context could be provided by more specific tags easily

Comment: A contextual tag is by definition not ambiguous, the main tag provides the context.  A tag like [python-range] doesn't work, nobody looks at it and nobody is an expert at it for the next 10 years.  While [python] [range] has good odds of finding an SO user that knows python and is familiar with ranges as well.

Comment: The "expert"-definition of tags is outdated IIRC. Additionally a contextual tag can't be "by definition not ambiguous", since it's dependent on context what that tag signifies. Quoting from the ["rules for tag burnination"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191): **`Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?`** Additionally I think 5 followers vs 3.4k questions paints a clear picture...

Comment: I don't see a use for a tag like `range` or even `python-range`. Both seem way too specific. Is the tag meant to help people finding answers or people answering questions? If there is an expert for all possible implementations of `range`, then I would think that would work. Otherwise, I would think that someone who is skilled with the language or framework in general would be more than capable to help answer questions that may/may not talk about `range` etc.

Comment: Note that burning, in the normal usage, *is* retagging, and no more.

Comment: There is the other kind of burnination.. TPTB press a button and the tag vanishes and is never ever seen again @Nathan This looks like the best alternative to me in this specific case.

Comment: @Turnerj would you mind explaining how range is 'way too specific'? In my post I make the point that the tag's defintion is ambiguous (and thus the tag is overly broad) and concerning your question... tags are labels to categorize questions and make them searchable...  both for seekers and answerers.

Comment: I agree with the first part of your question, `range` is ambiguous as it refers to 4 things. It however is also ultra specific (oxymoron I know), I couldn't see how having a `range` tag adds much more to the categorising of the question. The body of the question would likely have `range` in it so searching wouldn't really be affected. Basically, if we have a `range` tag, let's have a tag for every function in Python, then for every class in C# etc. I know I am exaggerating a bit but I feel that's what this would be leaning towards, tags for every tiny thing.

Comment: The wiki for 'range' gives four specific examples of ranges in programming (which seem to be chosen in an extremely arbitrary manner,) but the concept of ranges of values applies to pretty much every programming environment.

Comment: @HansPassant In the case that you mention, wouldn't simply tagging the question as [python] be sufficient? Is there such as thing as an expert in python who _isn't_ familiar with the concept of ranges of values? For that matter, is there such a thing as an expert in _any_ programming environment that isn't familiar with the concept of ranges of values?

Comment: @reirab, that's what I was trying to get at with my comments. Things like `range` are too specific where you wouldn't generally have an expert in *just that*. Experts in the specific language or platform likely can provide appropriate help for questions that would otherwise be tagged `range`.

Comment: Yep, all things considered this really doesn't seem like a useful tag.

Comment: This request needs a spiffy title. How about "This tag is out of [range]" or "Let's rage against [range]"?